# Scala covariant type declaration with an upper bound, why do methods need to repeat the upper bound exlplicitly

Tags: scala, generics, types, covariance

I have a trait that looks like this:

```
trait Processor[+T <: Document] {
  def process[D >: T <: Document](doc: D)
}
```

If I declare the `process` method with `process[D >: T](doc: D)`, I can't access the methods from the `Document` class.

I don't know why do I need to repeat the upper bound, the `<: Document`, in the `process` method.

So, two questions:

1. Is this the way it's supposed to be used?
2. Why doesn't the type system automatically pick up the upper bound from the trait definition.

Comment: In `process[D >: T](doc: D)`, the `D` is a supertype of `T` which is a subtype of `Document`, so `D` is not necessarily a `Document`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper bound in your method is on `D`, not on `T`. Say you do not put that upper bound, then `D` could be anything that `T` also is, for instance, `Any`. So the compiler must assume that `D` could be `Any`, and therefore cannot give you more methods.

Comment: Ha ha, yeah. Now I feel silly for asking the question. Thanks.